# How to replace values of a specific key in a array of objects?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a sample array of objects

```
[{"key": 0, "value": "Example1"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Example2"}, {"key": 2, "value": "Example3"}, {"key": 3, "value": "Example4"}]
```

And I have a data which includes `a, b, c, d`

Here `a` represents `Example1` which is first object `0`, `b` represents `Example2` which is second object `1` and so on.

How can I get the value of the object If I have a data of `a`?

Comment: Perhaps a Python tutorial on dictionaries would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

To properly change the value in an array of key_value objects you need to think about it like it's a dictionary inside a list.

```
dict_array = [{"key": 0, "value": "Example1"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Example2"}, {"key": 2, "value": "Example3"}, {"key": 3, "value": "Example4"}]
print(dict_array[0]['key'])
# 0
print(dict_array[1]['value'])
# 'Example2'
```

In this example, you are accessing the first value in the list (list index 0) and then it's value or key by it's name (dict['key']).

To change the value of 'a', which is the first dictionary in the list, you need to reasign the value of the key you want to change.

```
dict_array[0]['key'] = 'first_key'
dict_array[0]['value'] = 'first_key_example1'
print(dict_array)
# [{"key": 'first_key', "value": "first_key_example1"}, {"key": 1, "value": "Example2"}, {"key": 2, "value": "Example3"}, {"key": 3, "value": "Example4"}]
```